# WPF, TPL, Producer/Consumer Pattern - Wrong Thread Error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm new to TPL and WPf and have the following problem.
I try to download a site in an infinite loop (here only a for loop) and
add it to a Queue. The next Task takes it out and shows it in the Textblock.
However I don't seem to get the right Thread for the UI although I think that I use the TaskScheduler properly.

Thank you for any help!

```
BlockingCollection<string> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        Task task1 = new Task(
            (obj) =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        TxtBlock2.Text = "Task cancel detected";
                        throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string code = i.ToString() + "\t" + AsyncHttpReq.get_source_WebRequest(uri);
                        blockingCollection.Add(code);
                    }
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.Default);


        task1.ContinueWith(antecedents =>
        {
            TxtBlock2.Text = "Signalling production end";
            blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
        }, uiScheduler);


        Task taskCP = new Task(
            (obj) =>
            {
                while (!blockingCollection.IsCompleted)
                {
                    string dlCode;
                    if (blockingCollection.TryTake(out dlCode))
                    {
     //the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
                        TxtBlock3.Text = dlCode;  
                    }
                }
            }, uiScheduler);


WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess() + 0x4a bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0x19 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.Text.set(string value) + 0x24 bytes
```

> WpfRibbonApplication4.exe!WpfRibbonApplication4.MainWindow.Button1_Click.AnonymousMethod__4(object obj) Line 83 + 0x16 bytes    C#
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() + 0x44 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() + 0x43 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj) + 0x27 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) + 0x154 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) + 0x8b bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x7 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x147 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x2d bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

```
   System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
  Source=WindowsBase
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.set_Text(String value)
       at WpfRibbonApplication4.MainWindow.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Button1_Click>b__3(Object o) in C:\ ... \WpfRibbonApplication4\WpfRibbonApplication4\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 90
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException:
```

---

Thank you alot for all of your help.
I still have two question:
I rewrote my code a little bit with the Task.Factory.StartNew. However my Task2 seems to cause problems. There's no error message. Seems rather like a tight loop. Of course, I didn’t figure out why?
Would you be so kind and point me into the right direction again.
Keep in mind that I’ve been doing C# for ~6 months and TPL for a week otherwise I wouldn’t ask you again. But with this amount of experience ...
Thank you again!

Brians Code:

```
var task1 = new Task( 
  (obj) =>
```

Why is `obj` needed?

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
```

TaskScheduler uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
                BlockingCollection blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection();
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

```
            CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

            Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        string code = i++.ToString() + "\t" + AsyncHttpReq.get_source_WebRequest(uriDE);
                        blockingCollection.Add(code);
                    }
                }, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

            task1.ContinueWith(
                (antecedents) =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        TxtBlock2.Text = "Task cancel detected"; 
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        TxtBlock2.Text = "Signalling production end"; 
                    }

                    blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();

                }, uiTaskScheduler);


            Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    while (!blockingCollection.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        string dlcode;

                        if (blockingCollection.TryTake(out dlcode))
                        {
                            TxtBlock3.Text = dlcode;
                        }
                    }

                }, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiTaskScheduler);

        }
```

Comment: Can you please paste full stack trace? Also, is the method called from the UI thread initially to be started up?

Comment: Yes actually they are started from the ui thread.

It's all declared in the following event:

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { }

I pasted the stack above.

Comment: Sorry, can you paste the full exception details (i.e. exception.ToString())? This should absolutely work. Calling Dispatcher.[Begin]Invoke should not be necessary. Also you have a bug where if the work is canceled you will set the TextBlock2.Text in a non-UI scheduled task (task1).

Comment: I added it. I hope it's the right stacktrace. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, actually I just looked at your code again and the problem is simple: You're constructing a new `Task` instances manually using the constructor overload that takes a state object. There is no constructor overload that takes a `TaskScheduler`.

Normally people use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, so I didn't even notice that you were constructing the `Tasks` manually. When you construct `Task` instances manually, the proper way to specify the scheduler to run them on is to use the `Start` overload that takes a `TaskScheduler` instance. So in your case you would need to do:

```
taskCP.Start(uiTaskScheduler);
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so now the problem with your updated code is you've effectively scheduled a `Task` on UI (dispatcher) thread that is sitting there reading in a tight loop.

Now that the code is reworked, it becomes clear that you do *not* want to schedule task2 on the UI thread. If you want to push out notifications from there to the UI you can either call `Dispatcher::BeginInvoke` as suggested by another answer or you can start a new Task using the uiTaskScheduler inside of the loop. Calling Dispatcher::BeginInvoke will have less overhead and be clearer code wise IMHO, so I recommend just doing that.

Comment: Thanks. I added another and rewrote it with Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. It was rather a misunderstanding on my side on how tasks itselves work in combination with the Dispatcher. Thank you for your help in improving my code and showing me what I have to work on and practice in order to become better.

Comment: I had a feeling we might end up here from the beginning, but your real question was why your tasks weren't executing on the UI thread and I really wanted to get to the bottom of that to get the "right" answer to your question. Glad to help tho!

Comment: It's sometimes a little hard to ask a precise question without enough knowledge and experience. Some of the questions and problems arise during the conversation. I also had a problem with the generics and Intellisense.
 That's why I'm also thankful for your patience and unserstanding! Once again thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dispatcher to access UI thread like:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{TxtBlock2.Text = "Signalling production end";}));
```

Because a task runs in another thread other than UI thread, Dispatcher gives you a changes to access the thread which your UI at. MSDN gives a good explanation about it, please view the remark part at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: The dispatcher code worked like charm :). Thank you
I still don’t get why my TPL code doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

- There is no overload of the Task ctor that accepts a `TaskScheduler`. What you have actually done is passed the `TaskScheduler` to the `state` parameter that is then picked in your `obj` variable on the lambda expression.
- Because of the point above `taskCP` is actually running on the default scheduler and not `uiScheduler`.
- Because of the point above `taskCP` is attempting to access a UI element from a non-UI thread by modifying `TxtBlock3`.
- Likewise `task1` is attemping the same by modifying `TxtBlock2`.

Here is how I would refactor the code.

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
TaskScheduler ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

var task1 = new Task(
  () =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      string code = i.ToString() + "\t" + AsyncHttpReq.get_source_WebRequest(uri);
      queue.Add(code);
    }
  });

  task1.ContinueWith(
    antecedents =>
    {
      if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        TxtBlock2.Text = "Task cancel detected";
      }
      else
      {
        TxtBlock2.Text = "Signalling production end";
      }
      queue.CompleteAdding();
    }, ui);


  var taskCP = new Task(
    () =>
    {
      while (!queue.IsCompleted)
      {
        string dlCode;
        if (queue.TryTake(out dlCode))
        {
          Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
          {
            TxtBlock3.Text = dlCode; 
          }
        }
      }
    });

  task1.Start();
  taskCP.Start();
```

Notice that `ContinueWith` can accept a `TaskScheduler` and that is exactly what I have done above. I also have `taskCP` running on the default scheduler and then I use `Dispatcher.Invoke` before accessing `TxtBlock3`.

If you really want to start a `Task` on a specific scheduler then pass a `TaskScheduler` to the `Start` method like the following.

```
task1.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: Thank you Brian. I also added another question above

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` to invoke the code that use on UI elements from different thread. For example

```
string dlCode;
if (blockingCollection.TryTake(out dlCode))
{       
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
         TxtBlock3.Text = dlCode; 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can I also do it with the TPL, that means follow the pattern above?

Comment: Thank you, but that part works perfectly, but the problem is the part with TxtBlock3.Text = dlCode

Comment: Use the `Dispatcher.Invoke` in the code that accessing the UI elements from another thread, like in your `TextBoxl3.Text`

Comment: Thanks I'll try the dispatcher, and see if I can make this one work.